# How to force subclasses to implement a field using abstract base class in Python?

Tags: python, abc

Abstract base class can force implementation of a method by all it's child classes using `@abstractmethod` decorator. Can the same be done with class fields?

Say we have the following classes:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class AbsHero(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def say_hello():
        """Hero greeting"""
    

class GoodHero(AbsHero):
    def __init__(name: str):
        self.name = name
        
    def say_hello():
        print('Hi, my name is ' + self.name + '.')
        
        
class SneakyHero(AbsHero):
    def say_hello():
        print("I am sneaky, I don't have a name")
```

I want to enforce all children of `AbsHero` to have `name` field, or at least property. Right now both child classes are valid. What can I do, to make `GoodHero` class to work well, but `SneakyHero` declaration to cause failure?

Comment: That "name" is just an entry in each instances `__dict__`. The class doesn't really know about it.